# How do I stop from getting one of my this.state properties to stop getting undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to develop a simple app that calls stock data when the users inputs a certain symbol and then pushes click. The information shows up when I console.log(data.symbol) under the fetch method but when I try to use it on the handleSubmit function, it tells me symbol is not defined when it under this.state.symbol in my constructor method. I have tried to look up similar examples to my problems but it doesn't resolve the issue. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
class Symbol extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                value: '',
                symbol: [],
                isLoaded: false,
            };
        }
    
        getSymbol = (e) => { //use arrow function to get value of this
            this.setState({ // change state of state
                value: e.target.value.toUpperCase()
            });
            console.log(this.state.value)
        }
    
        handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault(),
                this.setState({
                    value: symbol
                })
            console.log(symbol)
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        }
    
        componentDidMount() { //run after the render method
            fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=${key}`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        symbol: data.map(data => {
                            data.symbol
                        })
                    });
                },
                    (error) => {
                        this.setState({
                            isLoaded: true,
                            error
                        });
                    }
                )
        }
    
        render() {
    
            const { symbol, data, value } = this.state
            if (value === symbol) {
                return console.log('same')
            }
    
            return (
                <div className="enterstock">
                    <h1 className="title">Enter A Stock Symbol</h1>
                    <span className="symbol">{"(" + " " + this.state.value + " " + ")"}</span>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="inputfields">
                        <input type="text" name="sym" className="sym" onChange={this.getSymbol}></input>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Symbol />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

Comment: can you explain which this.state.property is undefined

Comment: @ShauryaVardhanSingh Hi, the this.state.symbol is undefined under the handleSubmit function

Comment: you are currenty using this.setState({value: symbol}) whereas it should be this.setState({value: this.state.symbol})

Comment: @ShauryaVardhanSingh That helped but now other errors are popping up. Thanks for your help with my first problem!

Comment: What other errors can you point those out?

Comment: @ShauryaVardhanSingh I am logging this.state.symbol to the console and it keeps telling me that it is undefined. It gives me the array of the information I need.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that are wrong with your component here

- You don't need to bind this to an arrow function
- Where is `symbol` coming from inside handleSubmit?
- Where is the error coming from after `.then()` inside `componentDidmount`
- as SetState works Asynchronously, you won't find `this.state.value` right on the next line of a setState use a callback to setState like this

```
this.setState({value: e.target.value.toUpperCase()}, () => console.log(this.state.value))
```

Here is the updated code, which should work for you:

```
class Symbol extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      symbol: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  getSymbol = (e) => {
    //use arrow function to get value of this
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value.toUpperCase() },
      () => console.log(this.state.value)
    );
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(),
      this.setState({
        value: this.state.symbol,
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    //run after the render method
    fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=${key}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          symbol: data.map((item) => item.symbol),
        });
      })
      .catch((error) =>
        this.setState({ isLoaded: true, error, })
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { symbol, data, value } = this.state;
    if (value === symbol) {
      return console.log("same");
    }

    return (
      <div className="enterstock">
        <h1 className="title">Enter A Stock Symbol</h1>
        <span className="symbol">
          {"(" + " " + this.state.value + " " + ")"}
        </span>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="inputfields">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="sym"
            className="sym"
            onChange={this.getSymbol}
          ></input>
          <button type="submit" className="btn">
            Send
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Symbol />, document.getElementById("root"));
```